# Spring Security StackOverflowError loadUserByUsername()

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

- Spring Boot version 2.4.2
- Java version 1.8.

I am new at Spring and tried to authentication with JPA. I implemented WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter with 2 configuration methods. When i logged in with correct email and password, it redirect correct url; however, when i tried to logged in with incorrect email or password, it called loadUserByUsername until program crash.

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:411) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1593) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.getSingleResult(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1641) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getSingleResult(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:111) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor45.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$DeferredQueryInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:406) ~[spring-orm-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy90.getSingleResult(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$SingleEntityExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:196) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:88) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:155) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:143) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryQueryMethodInvoker$$Lambda$956/362373136.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:152) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:131) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388) ~[spring-tx-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:145) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy78.findByEmail(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at tr.gov.tubitak.ulakbim.test.kazan.service.UserService.loadUserByUsername(UserService.java:34) ~[main/:na]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:93) ~[spring-security-core-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java:133) ~[spring-security-core-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:182) ~[spring-security-core-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:201) ~[spring-security-core-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter$AuthenticationManagerDelegator.authenticate(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:510) ~[spring-security-config-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:201) ~[spring-security-core-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:201) ~[spring-security-core-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter$AuthenticationManagerDelegator.authenticate(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:510) ~[spring-security-config-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:201) ~[spring-security-core-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:201) ~[spring-security-core-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
```

***UserRepository.java***

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {
    User findByEmail(String email);
}
```

***UserService.java***

```
@Service
public class UserService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;


    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        UserBuilder builder = null;
        User user = userRepository.findByEmail(email);
        if (user==null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(email);
        }else{
            builder = org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User.withUsername(email);
            builder.password(user.getPassword());
            builder.roles(user.getRole());
        }
        return builder==null ? null : builder.build();
    }

}
```

***SecurityConfiguration.java***

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.parentAuthenticationManager(authenticationManagerBean())
                .userDetailsService(userService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/kurum*").hasAnyRole("ADMIN","USER")
                .antMatchers("/users*").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .and()
            .formLogin();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to `super.configure(auth);` line inside `configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)` method become solution for me.

```
 @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        // Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Filter execution threw an exception] with root cause
        // StackOverflowError: null
        super.configure(auth);

        auth.parentAuthenticationManager(authenticationManagerBean())
                .userDetailsService(userService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution can be using `.userDetailsService` instead of using `.parentAuthenticationManager` inside `configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)` method.

You should use `parentAuthenticationManager` with `super.configure()`.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userService);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/kurum*").hasAnyRole("ADMIN","USER")
                .antMatchers("/users*").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .and()
            .formLogin();
    }

}
```